# python 2.7. How to open an independent terminal inheriting globals and current folder

Tags: python, python-2.7, terminal, directory, global

From a python program I need to open a new independent terminal(has to stay alive after closing my program) that also has to inherit the globals of the current one(globals set before with os.environ) and the current working folder (set with os.chdir).
I'm using python 2.7 with PyQt4 in a KDE desktop.
I have tried with:

```
qproc=QProcess.startDetached("konsole")
os.command("bash -c konsole")
os.openpty()
pty.openpty()
pty.spawn("")
subprocess.call("kommand",shell=True)
os.system("bash -c konsole")
os.system("konsole")
```

But no luck yet. 
Oh, I'm trying with 'konsole' but other alternatives (working in KDE) would be great also.
Any ideas?
Thanks

Update: Of course I did not try that all together. One line in each test.

Comment: What was the problem with os.system("konsole") ?

Comment: George, the problem is that it's not opening the same folder than its parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the following? The `&` at the end will run the command in the background - it will not block your script.

```
os.system("konsole --workdir " + os.getcwd() + "&")
```

According to the python docs os.system preserves the env for the process it creates.

Comment: Well os.system worked before, with one problem: it's not opening the same working folder than the parent one(set with os.chdir).

Comment: You can set the directory as a parameter for konsole. Answer edited.